# [ROS2] colcon test discovery

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am writing some tests for my ROS2 Python package. I want to specify different levels of tests (unittest, integrationtests, system tests, ...) and run them with `colcon test` . I have the different tests in subfolders in the test directory:

```
my_pkg
├── launch
│   └── example.launch.py
├── my_pkg
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── my_node.py
│   ├── publisher.py
│   ├── subscriber.py
│   └── transformer.py
├── package.xml
├── README.md
├── resource
│   └── my_pkg
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
└── test
    ├── integrationtest
    │   └── test_integration.py
    └── unittest
        ├── test_pytest.py
        └── test_unittest.py
```

Colcon detects all tests, what is great. But sometimes I only want run e.g. the tests in the directory unittests. That woult be useful, because some of my integration or system tests needs a long time!

Are there any possibilities to run a specific subfolder of the test directory with `colcon test`? Have `colcon` some command line arguments for this?
Or is there another way to go?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374906/%5Bros2%5D-colcon-test-discovery/) by [lmiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/48153/lmiller/) on ROS Answers with karma: 219 on 2021-03-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) on 2021-03-29**:
Someone can correct me if I am wrong, but from my understanding of `colcon test`, there isn't a built-in way of selecting to only run tests from a given sub-folder of a package.

A workaround that comes to mind would be to create sub-packages (e.g. `my_pkg_integrationtest`, `my_pkg_unittest`) and to list them in `my_pkg`'s `package.xml` as test_dependencies.

But I'd be surprised if there wasn't someone more knowledgeable out there with a better solution than that

**Comment by [lmiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/48153/lmiller/) on 2021-03-30**:
Thanks for your reply.
My first thought was also that I could call up the various tests via side-/sub-packages. However, I dont like the structure of my repository with too many sub-packages.
As a current workaround I call `pytest` instead of `colcon test` like:

```
python3 -m pytest my_pkg/test/integrationtest
```

If someone has another way to call the tests only from a subfolder please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`colcon` simply invokes the unit testing framework used by each package when `colcon test` is being called.

If that testing framework has command line options to select/deselect specific tests you can easily provide them through `colcon`. E.g. for `pytest` you can use `colcon test --pytest-args ...` and use any of the sophisticated options like:

- markers with `-k` (https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/markers.html#marking-test-functions-and-selecting-them-for-a-run) or
- regular expression with `-m` (https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/markers.html#using-k-expr-to-select-tests-based-on-their-name).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2021-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2